# Variable in parent scope not getting altered in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, opentok

I'm using the opentok SDK for video chatting, and I need to create sessions. It's pretty straightforward, and that part's working fine. This is all being done in node.js, server side.

The issues is - and it's mostly cause I still don't quite get var scopes (especially with anonymous functions and closures) - I have a value inside of my anonymous function that I want to access (preferably by assigning it to another var, one that's in its parent scope), but can't!

Something like this:

```
function generateSession(session){
  var session='';
   opentok.createSession(function(error, sessionId){
      if (error) {
        throw new Error("Session creation failed.");
      }
      session = sessionId;
   });
   return session;
}
```

`session` retains it's initial value of '' (empty string), not the `sessionId` it was assigned to. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a question about *scope*. It's about asynchronicity. Your anonymous function *will* update the `session` variable in the parent function; but because your anonymous function is asynchronous, it'll happen *after* `generateSession` has returned.

Instead, you'll need to modify `generateSession` to accept a callback, and execute the callback (passing the generated `session`), once it's completed;

```
function generateSession(session, cb){
   opentok.createSession(function(error, sessionId){
      if (error) {
        throw new Error("Session creation failed.");
      }

      cb(sessionId);
   });
}

generateSession(blahblahblah, function (session) {
    // Access session here.
});
```

This is the exact same problem as for [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) (in that situation, it's the "success" callback that is asynchronous); there might be a more suitable duplicate, but I can't find one :(. It'll still be beneficial to read through it though.

Comment: Agh! Can't believe I didn't see this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`createSession` is an asynchronous function. Its callback is not executed until some time after `generateSession` has finished. You need to pass in a callback instead:

```
function generateSession(cb){
  opentok.createSession(cb);
}

generateSession(function(err, sessionId) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // use sessionId
});
```